# Clojure: Can't find codec for a class

Tags: clojure, codec

I'm querying a mongodb collection using monger like so:

```
(mc/find-one db "users" {:userId user-id})
```

But I get the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.
```

How do I fix it?

-- EDIT --

This is how I connect to mongodb using monger:

```
(let [uri mongo-uri
      {:keys [conn db]} (mg/connect-via-uri mongo-uri-only)]


  (defroutes myroutes
    (GET "/someroute" req
         (let [user-id (get-user-info (:access_token (json/read-str (:body (get-authentication-response csrf-token req)) :key-fn keyword)))]
           (mc/find-one db "users" {:user-id user-id})))
  )
```

And going to `/someroute` gives me the error I mentioned.

Comment: can you post more of the code (i.e. what package are you using and how do you connect to MongoDB)?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer, check out my edit.

Comment: This isn't a Clojure error, it's an error in the BSON serialization library used by your MongoDB client. Generally you shouldn't be trying to serialize a HttpClient implementation class at all; they *aren't* things that can be serialized to JSON or its binary cousin BSON.

Comment: ...so I'd start by trying to figure out if your `user-id` object really has the type you think it does. If it is or contains a handle on your HttpClient, well, there's your problem.